# Issues with calling method from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've found some good posts about using methods in other forms and tried to implement them in my code, but I'm getting a null object error (specifically, the frmAddMaterials object is null). Code compiles fine, error occurs when trying to use the create materials button on the second form.

My first form has an array to hold material information. When the user clicks a link on this first form, they are prompted with a second form where they can enter custom material information in the event that the material they are interested in using is not on designed in. Upon clicking "Add material" on form 2, I would like the RefreshMaterials() method on the first form to run, which creates a new entry in the array based on information from the second form.

Form1:

```
public partial class frmSnapFitMain : Form
{
    public frmMat frmAddMaterials;
    public Materials[] material = new Materials[20]; 
    Image[] problemtype = new Image[7]; 


private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender,LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        frmMat frmAddMaterials = new frmMat(this);
        frmAddMaterials.Show();
    }    


public void RefreshMaterials()
    {
        material[Materials.MaterialCount] = new Materials(frmAddMaterials.txtName.Text, Double.Parse(frmAddMaterials.txtFlex.Text), Double.Parse(frmAddMaterials.txtFriction.Text), Double.Parse(frmAddMaterials.txtStrain.Text)); //little m, materials here is for specific instance
        cboxMatSelect.Items.Add(frmAddMaterials.txtName.Text);
        frmAddMaterials.txtName.Text = ""; //reset fields
        frmAddMaterials.txtFlex.Text = "";
        frmAddMaterials.txtFriction.Text = "";
        frmAddMaterials.txtStrain.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
 public partial class frmMat : Form
{
    private readonly frmSnapFitMain _form1;

    public frmMat(frmSnapFitMain Form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._form1 = Form1;
    }

    public void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._form1.RefreshMaterials();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void frmMat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How does this even compile. Your line here frmMat frmAddMaterials = new frmMat(this); should not include frmMat in from of frmAddMaterials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1` method you declare a new instance of `frmMat`. This instance happens to have the same name of the global variable but it is a local one that disappears when you exit from the method.

```
 private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender,LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is not the global variable frmAddMaterials. 
    // It is a local one to this method
    frmMat frmAddMaterials = new frmMat(this);
    frmAddMaterials.Show();
}
```

Of course this means that in your **RefreshMaterials** you use the global variable that has never been initialized

You just need to remove the declaration of a local variable and initialize the global one

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender,LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // This initializes the global variable
    frmAddMaterials = new frmMat(this);
    frmAddMaterials.Show();
}
```

Said that it is always a good practice to use a *'defensive programming attitude'* when using global variables and test if the variable has been correctly initialized.

```
public void RefreshMaterials()
{
    if(frmAddMaterials != null)
    {
        material[Materials.MaterialCount] = new Materials(.....)         
        cboxMatSelect.Items.Add(frmAddMaterials.txtName.Text);
        frmAddMaterials.txtName.Text = ""; //reset fields
        frmAddMaterials.txtFlex.Text = "";
        frmAddMaterials.txtFriction.Text = "";
        frmAddMaterials.txtStrain.Text = "";
    }
}
```

I also suggest to subscribe to the `FormClosing` event of `frmAddMaterials` to set your instance to null when the form closes

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender,LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if(frmAddMaterials != null)
    {
        frmAddMaterials = new frmMat(this);
        frmAddMaterials.Show();
        frmAddMaterials.FormClosing += frmMaterialsClosing;
    }
}    
private void frmMaterialsClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    frmAddMaterials = null;
}
```

This allows you to restart the 'cycle' because when you click again the linklabel your global variable is null and you could reinitialize it to the new instance created in the linklabel click event handler.